# Not able schedule Airflow jobs which has shell scripts to execute hive queries

Tags: python, bash, hive, airflow

I am trying to schedule a shell script that has some hive queries.
Below are the respective files:

Airflow Dags:

```
from random import randint
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator, BranchPythonOperator
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime

with DAG("load_data_dag",start_date=datetime(2022,1,1),schedule_interval="@daily",catchup=False) as dag:
    
    create_ddl_hive=BashOperator(
        task_id="create_ddl_hive",
        #bash_command="helo"
        bash_command="scripts/create_ddl_hive.sh "
    )

    
create_ddl_hive
```

create_ddl_hive.sh has the below code:

```
#!/bin/bash
  
cd /users/mitku/Desktop/GoToDocs/Kisanu/Work/HQL/banking
hive -f create_banking_src.hql
echo "Script executed from: ${PWD}"
echo "Tables Created"
```

Hive SQL File:

```
create external table if not exists banking_src
(
age integer,
job string,
marital string,
education string,
default string,
balance integer,
housing integer,
loan integer,
contract string,
day integer
)
row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
stored as TEXTFILE
location '/banking_hadoop'
TBLPROPERTIES("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

**The job gets successfully started but when it encounters the cd and hive commands in the shell script, it gives the below errors**

```
[2022-01-19 14:55:15,314] {subprocess.py:63} INFO - Running command: ['bash', '-c', '#!/bin/bash\n\ncd /users/mitku/Desktop/GoToDocs/Kisanu/Work/HQL/banking;\n\nhive -f create_banking_src.hql;\n\necho "Script executed from: ${PWD}";\n\necho "Tables Created";\n\n']
[2022-01-19 14:55:15,331] {subprocess.py:74} INFO - Output:
[2022-01-19 14:55:15,337] {subprocess.py:78} INFO - bash: line 2: cd: /users/mitku/Desktop/GoToDocs/Kisanu/Work/HQL/banking: No such file or directory
[2022-01-19 14:55:15,338] {subprocess.py:78} INFO - bash: line 4: hive: command not found
[2022-01-19 14:55:15,339] {subprocess.py:78} INFO - Script executed from: /tmp/***tmpz6rqynii
[2022-01-19 14:55:15,340] {subprocess.py:78} INFO - Tables Created
```

Can anyone suggest alternatives to fix this?

PS: the script location is in the dag folder under the AIRFLOW home path. Additionally, the airflow is running under a docker container.

Comment: that shell script should be executed on hive/hadoop cluster node. ssh to node, run script there

Comment: You shouldn't rely on exact host filepaths from Airflow. If you need files, they should be packaged and distributed with the job. Or install pyspark in your jobs, and use it to create Hive tables

Comment: Or use pyhive - https://github.com/dropbox/PyHive

Answer (score 0):

From the error I don't think the hive client is installed on the machine where the Airflow worker is trying to run. If you can run the `hive` command on the machine, then you should probably use the HiveOperator from Airflow. If you are on Airflow 2.x, you will have to install the **apache-airflow-providers-apache-hive** package.

You should run the command from the bash operator directly is if the hive client is installed on the machine running the airflow worker.

```
from random import randint
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator, BranchPythonOperator
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime

with DAG("load_data_dag",start_date=datetime(2022,1,1),schedule_interval="@daily",catchup=False) as dag:
    
    create_ddl_hive=BashOperator(
        task_id="create_ddl_hive",
        bash_command="bash /users/mitku/Desktop/GoToDocs/Kisanu/Work/HQL/banking/create_ddl_hive.sh "
    )

    
    create_ddl_hive
```

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes, you are right I will follow the same then.

Comment: thanks for this, let me try this as well, by the way when you say **If you can run the hive command on the machine, then you should probably use the HiveOperator from Airflow** , do you mean the hive should be installed within the container, or in the machine, because I can run hive queries in my machine separately.